# How to set width and heigh of UIButton that is added as custom view of UIBarButtonItem when using SVG images?

Tags: ios, swift, svg, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I am having a vector image, downloaded from [phosphor-icons](https://phosphoricons.com/):

I have downloaded .svg version of an icon.
When you open this vector file in image editor, you see that it has `192x192` dimensions.
Which I guess its not relevant at all when it comes to vectors files, but...

I have this code:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))

button.imageView?.contentMode  = .scaleAspectFit
button.backgroundColor = .yellow
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "alien"), for: .normal)
button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item], animated: true)
```

Now the thing is, if I use this original `svg` image(192x192), a button shrinks and it looks like this:

[image: alien-big]

but I don't want this button to have these dimensions, but rather those that are set with:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))
```

Now, if I go to an image editor, and change the size of this vector file to `22x22` (it still stays `svg` file), it shows up like this:

[image: alien-normal]

which looks how I want.

The thing is, I thought that Xcode will generate required `png` file from this `svg` based on device's pixel density. So in this case, say, on newer devices that use `@3x` images, at compile time, cause my button is defined as `32x32` points, a `96px X 96px` image will be created and used as `@3x` image.

Also, I thought that this is going to work like described, no matter what "dimensions" a physical .`svg` file is, cause it's a **vector**, and it should be up/down scaled as view dictates. Where I am wrong with this, and how to make this button to look the same as from second image, no matter of what are actual .`svg` dimensions?

EDIT:

In Attributes Inspector, for this asset, I have set *Preserve Vector Data* and selected *Single Scale* option.

Comment: You don't set the width property of the UIBarButtonItem?

Comment: I did try something like `item.width = 32` but it doesn't affect on actual width at all. @Shadowrun

Comment: What I have figured out, is that I can apply width and height constraint on button. That it works as it should...But certainly I am curious, can this be achieved without manually applied autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of to achieve this without using autolayout constraints  , like you commented , is using a `UIView()` for `customview`

```
   let view = UIView(frame: button.frame)
   view.addSubview(button)

   let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
   self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

When adding a button as the `customView` for a bar button item, UIKit will automatically use auto-layout.

So, your init of `UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 32, height: 32))` doesn't have any effect.

I grabbed that "alien.svg" from the site you linked to and used it un-edited, with these settings:

[image]

Then, using this code (in `viewDidLoad()`):

```
    let button = UIButton()
    
    button.backgroundColor = .yellow
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "alien"), for: .normal)
    button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)

    // adding the button as a custom bar button item view
    //  automatically uses auto-layout
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

    // you can use either
    //navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = item
    
    // or
    navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([item], animated: true)
```

We get this result:

[image]